# numpy 1D array to numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to read a 1D numpy array in Python and generate two other numpy arrays:

- first one is the input, if there is no 'nan' values. Otherwise, input with 'nan' values replaced by '0'
- second one is a mask, 1='input value is not 'nan'', and '0'='input value is nan''

For example:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,numpy.nan,4])
```

would give

```
[1,2,0,4]
[1,1,0,1]
```

What's the most efficient way to do this in python ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [`numpy.ma.masked_invalid()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html).  It kind of gives you both of these.

Comment: It looks good, although the array is masked with '--'. There does not seem to be any configuration for the mask value. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `nan` to `0`, use [`numpy.nan_to_num`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,numpy.nan,4])
>>> numpy.nan_to_num(a)
array([ 1.,  2.,  0.,  4.])
```

Use [`numpy.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html#numpy.isnan) to convert `nan` to `True`, non-nan numbers to `False`. Then substract them from `1`.

```
>>> numpy.isnan(a)
array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> 1 - numpy.isnan(a)
array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for :) Vikash's solution also does it fine. For the last command, I managed to do it also with the ~ sign instead of substracting one.

Comment: @carmellose, I slightly updated the answer code. You don't need to use `astype` if use `1 - numpy.isnan(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

for first one:

```
numpy.nan_to_num(a)
```

second one:

```
numpy.invert(numpy.isnan(a)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert NaNs to zeros, use:

```
numpy.nan_to_num(a)
```

To set 1 for non-NaNs and 0 for NaNs, try:

```
numpy.isfinite(a)*1
```